# Using Fabric Node SDK 1.4.x with Fabric 2.0

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

We have just migrated to Fabric 2.0 and all of our components (peer, orderer, binaries) are at v2.0.0.

Our Fabric Node SDK is still at v1.4.8 and most of its functions are working such as

`createChannel, updateChannel, installChaincode etc.`

However, when I try to use `Channel.sendInstantiateProposal`, I get an error

`"Channel <channel_name> has been migrated to the new lifecycle. LSCC is now read only".`

I get the fact that this is likely a mismatch between the SDK and the Fabric components, however, is there any way to get this to work besides upgrading to Fabric Node SDK 2.0?

The configtx.yaml file used to bring up the network has `capabilities all set to V2.0:true`. The notes indicate that V2.0 capabilities are non-backward compatible so I am assuming I cannot set them to V1.4 and still work with Fabric 2.0 components.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/upgrade.html) seems to confirm your assumption that SDKs are not necessarily forward-compatible when it comes to new features, such as the new chaincode lifecycle (see the blue 'Note' box).

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the v1.4 SDK is compatible with v2, but the new chaincode architecture in v2 does not have an instantiation of the chaincode as part of its lifecycle. Instead, it uses a new, four-step process as defined in the [official documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/chaincode_lifecycle.html#install-and-define-a-chaincode). This is why the v1.4 SDK is failing at that line in particular, where you call Channel.sendInstantiateProposal(). The SDK is working fine, but that operation is not supported by the new chaincode lifecycle.

As for a solution, unfortunately, in v2 SDK there is no way to perform administrative tasks, and you have to use the Peer CLI for such operations.

Comment: Thank you. I realized that from the documentation as well as chatting with Dadid Kelly on the Hyperledger chat.